# Why are there a mass of tasks for loading a CSV file in S3 bucket?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

i have a small spark standalone cluster with dynamic resource allocation which uses aws s3 as storage, then i start a spark sql, create a hive external table loading data from a 779.3KB csv file in s3 bucket, when i execute a sql "select count(1) from sales;", there exactly are 798009 tasks in the spark sql job, just like a task per byte. And "spark.default.parallelism" doesn't work. Is there any advice?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Hadoop 2.6 JARs then it's a bug in that version of s3a; if you are seeing it elsewhere then it may be a config problem.

Your file is being split into one partition per byte because the filesystem is saying "each partition is one byte long". Which means that `FileSystem.getBlockSize()` is returning the value "0" (cf. [HADOOP-11584](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11584): *s3a file block size set to 0 in getFileStatus*).

For s3a connector, make sure that you are using 2.7+ and then set `fs.s3a.block.size` to something like `33554432` (i.e. `32MB`), at which point your source file won't get split up at all.

If you can go up to 2.8; we've done a lot of work speeding both input and output, especially with column format IO and its seek patterns.

Answer (score -1):

Try DF.repartition(1) before running the query. There must too many number of partition when you are running this command.

Answer (score -1):

use spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2